# existence of subgroups of finite abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

For finite cyclic groups with order $n$, it is known that for every divisor $d|n$ there is a subgroup of order $d$. Is this statement true in general for finite abelian groups?

Comment: yeah but $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is itself a proper subgroup

Comment: By the Chinese remainder theorem it suffices to prove this when $n$ is a prime power, where it's true by inspection. This is true more generally for finite nilpotent groups (you again reduce to the case of $p$-groups and then induct).